# Laravel 5.2 using namespaces

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've just upgraded my application from *Laravel 4.2* to *Laravel 5.2* and i'm having some trouble making everything to work. Currently i'm having a problem with classes like Auth, Lang, and all of my models. The problem is that when i go /public/ i get a *Fatal error: Class 'Lang' not found*. I've fixed this by adding `use Lang;` to my Controller but then another class is not found unitl i add every to `use` statement. This also goes for all of my models that are placed in *app/Modules* and are `namespaced` with *App\Models* My question is next, do i need to use the `use` statement for every class i want to load or is there a normal way? Thanks

Comment: this is a normal way, if you want to load function of a class you have to start with use ClassName

Comment: I know how to use the `use` statement but isn't it a drag to load every single class one by one? In *Laravel 4.2* all modules and packages were loaded by default

Comment: yes, you have to load every single class i.e use Auth, Hash, Input, Session, Redirect, Str, Validator, Mail; even if you want to load model in your controller you have to use App\User

Comment: What a drag... Thanks for the help